# Registering different Post Formats for Blog Post and CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, post-formats, add-theme-support, post-type-support

I'm using following code to register post formats for my blog posts ...

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'video', 'audio' ) );
```

Now, i want to add post formats support for my CPT 'Portfolio' too, but using different set of post formats. Using this code will add post format support for my CPT ...

```
add_post_type_support( 'portfolio', 'post-formats' );
```

But i only want to register *gallery* and *video* post format for portfolio CPT. Using the code below does'nt work ...

```
add_post_type_support( 'portfolio', 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'video' ) );
```

What code should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative approach.

There is a unique class in body tag for each post type. e.g for *portfolio* post type i can use the CSS code something like mentioned below to hide the extra option.

```
.post-type-portfolio #post-format-audio, /* for radio button itself */
.post-type-portfolio .post-format-audio /* for option label */
{
    display: none;
}
```

Hope it helps anybody else.